# JavaFX CSS: How to set tabpane tabs - width, height

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am trying to make tabs that have a minimum width and height, for finger-size on a touch screen, and not the size of the text within.

```
.tab-pane *.tab-header-area *.tab-header-background {
  -fx-background-color:transparent;
  -fx-tab-min-width:120px;
  -fx-tab-max-width:120px;
  -fx-tab-min-height:50px;
  -fx-tab-max-height:50px;
}

.tab {
  -fx-font-family: Arial;
  -fx-font-size: 18;
  -fx-background-color:royalblue ;
}

.tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color:blue ;
}
```

The colors and font are working, but the sizes have no effect.  I have tried a number of sizes, using px and em, but no effect.

```
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    Tab tab1 = new Tab();
    tab1.setText("Machine");
    tab1.setClosable(false);

    Tab tab2 = new Tab();
    tab2.setText("Shifts");
    tab2.setClosable(false);

    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
```

Comment: Have you imported the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, for the Scene.  As I say, I am getting the font and colors, but not sizes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The size properties you are trying to set are [properties of the `TabPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane).

The selector you use:

```
.tab-pane *.tab-header-area *.tab-header-background
```

selects the tab header background child of the tab header area child of the tab pane: that is a `StackPane` (see the "Substructure" section of the docs linked above). [`StackPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#stackpane) doesn't define those properties, so in your CSS they have no effect.

Set the size properties directly on the tab pane:

```css
.tab-pane *.tab-header-area *.tab-header-background {
  -fx-background-color:transparent;
}

.tab-pane {
  -fx-tab-min-width:120px;
  -fx-tab-max-width:120px;
  -fx-tab-min-height:50px;
  -fx-tab-max-height:50px;
}

.tab {
  -fx-font-family: Arial;
  -fx-font-size: 18;
  -fx-background-color:royalblue ;
}

.tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color:blue ;
}
```