# TabPane: Size and color

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to set the size of an actual "flap" of `Tab` within a `TabPane`? At least I want them to be the same size but even better if I can decide their size.

Comment: It is indeed, I always forget that there is CSS, too ...

Comment: Solution to be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37648017/230513